# In app purchase dynamic add items from server

Tags: ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I'm working on a singing app where people can purchase both our currency and the background music for a song. It's obvious that the currency is in consumable type however I'm confused on the the background music (or beats) because I've the following conditions.

1. The background music has to be purchased with in app purchase , not in our currency (we have agreement with the music provider).
2. There may be hundreds out music updated frequently , I can't manually register them in itunes connect.
   3 . We have a server store these music, an ideal flow will be the user purchase a particular bg music , he can then download it into device and we also keep record on server side.

I've first thought about create a general item as "Beat" . No matter what particular BG music user buy , I will treat it as purchase of this  "Beat" item. If possible what type should the item be ? or is there another way I can register these music one by one automatically? (get product id)

The app is almost done except this part . I'm kinda worry now. thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Not yet... I'm now trying to add a general consumable item but not sure if it will get approved by apple, still looking for a better solution

Comment: How did you solve this?